# Media queries with CSS animations

Tags: animation, css, media-queries, css-animations

I'm trying out some heavy CSS3 stuff here and am running into some issues that I hope can be cleared up:

1 - I have a box that slides in when you load the page. Let's say:

```
#box {
    animation-duration: 3.5s;  
    animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {  from { top: 0; }  to { top: 100%; }}
```

However, in my media query, because of some resizing, I need to modify this to be:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    @keyframes slidein {  from { top: 0; }  to { top: 80%; }}
}
```

I thought I could keep the animation name the same, and just redefine the keyframes inside one of the @media queries, however this does not seem to work. Why? (Yes, I have the proper prefixes set)

2 - My solution for above, is to define different animations for each size:

```
#box {
    animation-duration: 3.5s;  
    animation-name: slidein;
}

@keyframes slidein {  from { top: 0; }  to { top: 100%; }}
@keyframes slidein-low {  from { top: 0; }  to { top: 80%; }}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #box { 
        animation-name: slidein-low;
   }
}
```

However, NOW upon resizing the site, the animation will start over once it hits one of the media queries. I only want the animation to play once (whatever size it may be, and even with resizing afterwards), and that's it. So unless there's a solution to #1, I believe this is because when a query is detected, it kinda "re-initiates" the CSS for it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're doing the min-width for smaller screens that could possibly have a max width of 1024? So maybe try putting that in as well:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1024px) {
    #box { 
        animation-name: slidein-low;
   }
}
```

Maybe even try putting the animation construct in the query as well:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1024px) {

    @keyframes slidein-low {  from { top: 0; }  to { top: 80%; }}

    #box { 
        animation-name: slidein-low;
   }
}
```

I'm sure you've come across this site but just in case you haven't here's a nice reference for media queries:

http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries/

Answer (score 0):

From my experimenting, I've found that Safari 5 (for desktop and iOS) will most certainly render your page in the way you intend using either one of your solutions. Firefox 9, on the other hand, does not appear to respect @-moz-keyframe or -moz-animation rules if they are placed in @media blocks (and both ignore the W3C @keyframe and non-vendor specific animation properties)